# Why doesn't the for loop continue for the first staement?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have been building a code to transfer data from excel to word. To try that out I have built a code with an array list. To check each array in the word and place a string next to the list. But it is not taking the array in the loop.

```
Sub CreateNewWordDoc()

    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim arr(12)

    arr(0) = "(249_L), 38,7 %"
    arr(1) = "(248_R), 38,7 %"
    arr(2) = "(249_M), 38,7 "
    arr(3) = "(3560), 38,7 "
    arr(4) = "(3550), 38,7 %"
    arr(5) = "(349_), 38,7 %"
    arr(6) = "(348_), 38,7 %"
    arr(7) = "(451), 38,7 %"
    arr(8) = "(450L), 38,7 "
    arr(9) = "(450R), 38,7 "
    arr(10) = "(151), 38,7 %"
    arr(11) = "(150L), 38,7 %"
    arr(12) = "(150R), 38,7 %"

    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    wrdApp.Visible = True
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("E:\ShareDrive_Ruehl\full-flexible-MBS-models_report\example-report\FullFlexibleGearbox - Copy (2).docx")


    For i = 0 To 12


    wrdDoc.Application.Selection.Find.Text = arr(i)
    wrdDoc.Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    wrdDoc.Application.Selection.InsertBefore arr(i) & "test"

    Next
    End Sub
```

I am getting the output as seen in the figure. My intention was to find "`arr(i)`" and place `arr(i)` text before it. But it is just finding `array (0)` and pasting `arr(i)` text.

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you create a new instance of word instead of using the current one? This is word vba after all. Also if you use Find with `Selection` always use `Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd` before your `Next`.

Comment: I am using it in the excel vba so I am using it to open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code slightly adjusted. Note the use of `With` blocks for a slightly more "cleaned up" look, and the HomeKey to reset the selection before the next find:

```
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Dim i As Integer
Dim arr(12)

arr(0) = "(249_L), 38,7 %"
arr(1) = "(248_R), 38,7 %"
arr(2) = "(249_M), 38,7 "
arr(3) = "(3560), 38,7 "
arr(4) = "(3550), 38,7 %"
arr(5) = "(349_), 38,7 %"
arr(6) = "(348_), 38,7 %"
arr(7) = "(451), 38,7 %"
arr(8) = "(450L), 38,7 "
arr(9) = "(450R), 38,7 "
arr(10) = "(151), 38,7 %"
arr(11) = "(150L), 38,7 %"
arr(12) = "(150R), 38,7 %"
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("E:\ShareDrive_Ruehl\full-flexible-MBS-models_report\example-report\FullFlexibleGearbox - Copy (2).docx")
wrdDoc.Activate
wrdApp.Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory

For i = 0 To 12
    With wrdApp.Selection
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .text = arr(i)
            .Execute
        End With
        .InsertBefore arr(i) & "test"
        .HomeKey unit:=wdStory
    End With
Next
```

Note: your needs can most probably be achieved without using `Selection` but further info would be needed for that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @LocEngineer. I am getting a run time error 424. "Object required". Let me know if you know something regarding that.

Comment: I see. I have edited the code to be used from within Excel. Also `wrdApp.Documents.Open` without the wrdApp object caused the error. Should do it now.

Comment: Great Thank you @LocEngineer